# Find and replace in adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA loop which searches through an entire worksheet for, say, the word "COUNTRY", and every time it is encountered, it replaces the cell +1 to the right with the word "UK".

Rest assured that this is necessary and can't be done with a column of formulae, since the word COUNTRY is scattered around the worksheet a large number of times and in an irregular way.

I really wanted to start off with some code but I can't find the way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.  Unless you have code that is not working and need help overcoming a specific problem in that code, this question is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your VBA code,

```
Sub funcOffset()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For j = 1 To 255
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, j) = "COUNTRY" Or InStr(Cells(i, j), "COUNTRY") > 0 Then
        Cells(i, j + 1) = "UK"
    End If
Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Note:- the code is case sensitive and checks COUNTRY in upper case only. Alter it accordingly if you need.